# laravel php package conflict

Tags: php, laravel, facebook-php-sdk

I'd lie to using this lib: https://github.com/toolkito/laravel-social-auto-posting

Over a 5.4 Laravel installation.
It fail with this mex:

> Problem 1
>       - Installation request for toolkito/larasap ^1.2 -> satisfiable by toolkito/larasap[V1.2.2].
>       - Conclusion: remove laravel/framework v5.4.22
>       - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.4.22
>       - toolkito/larasap V1.2.2 requires illuminate/support 5.5.x|5.6.x -> satisfiable by illuminate/support[v5.5.0, v5.5.16, v5.5.17, v5.5.2, v5.5.28, v5.5.33, v5.5.34, v5.5.35, v5.5.36, v5.5.37, v5.5.39, v5.5.40, v5.5.41, v5.5.43, v5.6.0, v5.6.1, v5.6.10, v5.6.11, v5.6.12, v5.6.13, v5.6.14, v5.6.15, v5.6.16, v5.6.17, v5.6.19, v5.6.2, v5.6.20, v5.6.21, v5.6.22, v5.6.23, v5.6.24, v5.6.25, v5.6.26, v5.6.27, v5.6.28, v5.6.29, v5.6.3, v5.6.30, v5.6.31, v5.6.32, v5.6.33, v5.6.34, v5.6.35, v5.6.36, v5.6.37, v5.6.38, v5.6.4, v5.6.5, v5.6.6, v5.6.7, v5.6.8, v5.6.9].

So firstly I try to update Illuminate, by running:

```
composer require illuminate/support
```

but again, problems:

> Problem 1
>       - laravelcollective/html v5.4.1 requires illuminate/support 5.4.* -> satisfiable by illuminate/support[5.4.x-dev, v5.4.0, v5.4.13, v5.4.17, v5.4.19, v5.4.27, v5.4.36, v5.4.9] but these conflict with
>   your requirements or minimum-stability.
>       - laravelcollective/html v5.4.1 requires illuminate/support 5.4.* -> satisfiable by illuminate/support[5.4.x-dev, v5.4.0, v5.4.13, v5.4.17, v5.4.19, v5.4.27, v5.4.36, v5.4.9] but these conflict with
>   your requirements or minimum-stability.
>       - laravelcollective/html v5.4.1 requires illuminate/support 5.4.* -> satisfiable by illuminate/support[5.4.x-dev, v5.4.0, v5.4.13, v5.4.17, v5.4.19, v5.4.27, v5.4.36, v5.4.9] but these conflict with
>   your requirements or minimum-stability.
>       - Installation request for laravelcollective/html (locked at v5.4.1, required as ^5.3.0) -> satisfiable by
>   laravelcollective/html[v5.4.1].

I cannot change laravel version due the project that using Gentelella template, what do you suggest me to do for using this package?

Comment: try deleting `composer.lock` before doing the require

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are running into a second issue when trying to update illuminate/support.

First: `toolkito/larasap V1.2.2 requires illuminate/support 5.5.x|5.6.x`

Second: `Laravelcollective/html v5.4.1 requires illuminate/support 5.4.*`

You wont be able to use `toolkito/larasap V1.2.2` with Laravel 5.4.

If you update `illuminate/support` to 5.5/5.6 you'll have to update all your other components for Laravel to work properly, essentially updating Laravel to 5.6 which you cannot do.

Comment: its seem like that :(

Comment: I choose this package just because is well documented, any other good well doc package for posting over a fb's page?

Comment: I don't, sorry, if you're feeling adventurous you could try upgrading laravel to 5.5, the docs (https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/upgrade#upgrade-5.5.0) suggest it will only cake an hour shouldn't break your template assuming it's just front end?

Comment: thats link works for me! the update seems to be ok, and now Ive installed the package! so crossed fingers until next error :D thanks for the tips